# JS date string inside an object automatically gets converted to object if field name is time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm trying to use lightweight-charts and I need a field name `time`. So the structure should be something like this: `{time: '2022-05-05', value: 51.21}`

For some reason the date string I supply to time field automatically gets converted to an object like this: `{day: 9, month: 12, year: 2022}` even when it is clearly saved as a string. I changed the field name to something different like `date` and it goes back to just being a plain string like this: `2022-12-05`. But I wouldn't be able to use lightweight-charts with that field name.

My question is where is this auto-converting coming from? the dates come from momentjs using the format function like so: `moment(item.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString()`. I'm using react (if it has something to do with it).

EDIT:
I basically have an array of these objects: `{time: '2022-05-05', value: 51.21}` and I basically just push them into an array like this: `dataset.push({value: item.value, time: moment(item.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')})` Nothing special. I printed this array and it would spit out something like this: `[{value: 51.15, time: {day: 9, month: 12, year: 2022}}]`. but when I changed the field to `date` it prints this out: `[{value: 51.15, time:'2022-12-09']`.

I also tried creating a formatter function and saving it as string literal. So it loops through the dataset again and save it like this: `time: '${item.time}'` and it prints out: `[{value: 53.1, time: [Object object]}]` so we can confirm that it is automatically being converted as an object

this is basically just the code:

```
while (moment(latestTime).diff(oldestTime, 'day') >= 0) {
  dataset.push({ time: `${moment(latestTime).format('yyyy-MM-DD').toString()}` })
  latestTime = moment(latestTime).subtract(1, 'day')
}
```

Another EDIT:
This is the entire code:

```js
// mock response data
const response = { data: [{create_tz: "2022-12-09T12:50:43.853156+00:00"}, {create_tz: "2022-12-08T12:50:43.853156+00:00"}, {create_tz: "2022-12-06T12:50:43.853156+00:00"}] }
// actual code follows
const { data } = response // this is from an API response
const dataset = []
const oldestTime = moment(data[data.length - 1].create_tz)
let latestTime = moment(data[0].create_tz)
while (moment(latestTime).diff(oldestTime, 'day') >= 0) {
  dataset.push({value: 51.6, time: `${moment(latestTime).format('yyyy-MM-DD').toString()}` })
  latestTime = moment(latestTime).subtract(1, 'day')
}
console.log(dataset)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you post an example that reproduces the error?

Comment: *"where is this auto-converting coming from?"* - We can't see your code, so we can't know.  What debugging have you done to narrow down where/when the value changes?  If you're suggesting that web browsers just **always** do this then that's pretty hard to believe...

Comment: I made some updates, thank you for your replies

Comment: how is `dataset` getting used? Is this going into some charting library? It may be converting it there? We need more context. JS doesn't just change the structure of objects automatically, something else is happening here

Comment: it does, it goes to a charting library but even before passing it to the chart and just printing it out immediately after the array was created, the time field already gets converted. Think of it like this: I created the object where I saved the date, pushed it to the array, and then printed the array. and now its converted automatically

Comment: are you pushing to an array that's already linked to a chart? Maybe they have some trigger when the array data changes to reformat it? Can you please post more of your code, we're just throwing shots into the dark right now

Comment: I've added the entire code related to this problem. I mean it seems so simple yet I have no clue what's causing it cause it's literally just pushing a string inside an object and then into the array.

Comment: I've created a snippet with your code and it is not reproducible. Something else is in play that we don't know about

Comment: Doesnt make sense, it's the exact same code, I updated the response to fit the format of our timestamp. But no luck, cant reproduce the bug. thank you for your input, I'll try looking into it more.